# Ajax form validate when submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

How do I write code within ajax block in order to validate form fields?

I need to check fields firstname, lastname and email before ajax request page described below. Basically if fields are empty do nothing. The chunk of code is below.

HTML is plain. Its submit is 
    `input class="red" id="send" type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message"`

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
jQuery( '#ajax_form' ).submit(function(){
  var data = jQuery( this ).serialize();

  jQuery.support.cors = true;

 // var email = $data("email").val();

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ecommerce.natopia.com/notifications/check-availability",
    data: data,
    success: function( data ){}
  });


//  closeCheckAvailability();
  return false;
});
});


function closeCheckAvailability(){
      $("div.on1").fadeOut("slow");
      $(".overOuter5").fadeOut("slow");
      $('.overOuter5').removeClass('displayBlock');
      $("#aa5").removeClass('displayBlock');
      $("#aa5").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `beforeSend`?

> beforeSend Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings ) A
>   pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in
>   jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to
>   set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as
>   arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend
>   function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend
>   option will be called regardless of the type of request.

ref:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ecommerce.natopia.com/notifications/check-availability",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(){
        //do your validation
    },
    success: function( data ){}
  });
```

Comment: Well, it should work like registration form at http://natopia.com/ Click at "Join Us"

Comment: Then I think you would use http://livevalidation.com/ plugin to ease your validation. It will prevent form submit until all fileds are validated.

Comment: It's not that simple. The form is within a ajax lightbox that fades out when form is submited. Thus the function must be able to stop process and warn what field is wronly filled with a small red message bellow the field. Do I make sense?

Comment: I understand, if your validations are not very complicated, then you wont need a php script to call every time the user types in every filed. Go ahead and take a look at the plugin. Using that, The form wont be submitted if one of your validations fails.

Comment: @luri, can you edit your question and include the source code that fades out the lightbox?

Comment: @RobertR, Sorry for my delay. It's added.

Comment: @luriSampaio Edit your question, not the answer.

Comment: @RobertR, What do you mean? hmmm...  well I added it again. I guess now it's properly added. Thanks!

Comment: Don't validate using Javascript. Unless you want me to come and hack you.

Comment: Well you could have been kind and answered the question at least!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `success` callback to close the lightbox. Put the validation code before the call to `jQuery.ajax` similar to below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
jQuery( '#ajax_form' ).submit(function(){
  var data = jQuery( this ).serialize();

  jQuery.support.cors = true;

  // do validation here
  if (not valid) {
      return false;  // exit the event handler without closing the lightbox.
  }

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ecommerce.natopia.com/notifications/check-availability",
    data: data,
    success: function( data ){closeCheckAvailability();}
  });

  return false;
});
});


function closeCheckAvailability(){
      $("div.on1").fadeOut("slow");
      $(".overOuter5").fadeOut("slow");
      $('.overOuter5').removeClass('displayBlock');
      $("#aa5").removeClass('displayBlock');
      $("#aa5").hide();
}
```